# I am unable to read the css ID of the pressed button in code behind ASP.NET

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I am unable to read the css ID of the pressed button in code behind.

Here is the method I have create however for             string btnCliked = ((Button)sender).ID; the ID is null I don't know why.

```
    protected void open_contract_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         
        string btnCliked = ((Button)sender).ID;
        foreach (contractStepColumn i_contractColumn in kanban.kanbanBoard)
        {

            foreach (contractTask contract_task in i_contractColumn.contractTasks)
            {
                if (btnCliked == "btnContractPopup" + i_contractColumn.stepColumnName + i_contractColumn.contractTasks.IndexOf(contract_task))
                {
                    KanbanUI.selectedContractID = contract_task.contract_id;
                    Redirect();
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Here is how my buttons are create in the code behind.

```
            Button btnMoreDetails = new Button();
            btnMoreDetails.Attributes.Add("class", "btnPopup");
            btnMoreDetails.Attributes.Add("ID", "btnContractPopup" + i_contractColumn.stepColumnName + i_contractColumn.contractTasks.IndexOf(contract_task));
            btnMoreDetails.Text = "Más Detalles";
            btnMoreDetails.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
            btnMoreDetails.Click += new EventHandler(this.open_contract_click);
            expandPopup.Controls.Add(btnMoreDetails);
```

Any help would be very appriciended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it didn't work is because of this line

```
  btnMoreDetails.Attributes.Add("ID", "btnContractPopup" + i_contractColumn.stepColumnName + i_contractColumn.contractTasks.IndexOf(contract_task));
```

For some reason asp.net is unable to read the id so I changed it to this

```
 btnMoreDetails.ID ="btnContractPopup" + i_contractColumn.stepColumnName + i_contractColumn.contractTasks.IndexOf(contract_task);
```

Despite the fact that in both case the css seems to be exactly the same to me.